# Is there a theoretical performance limit for Lithium Ion batteries?

Tags: batteries, energy, performance

Is there a theoretical performance limit for Lithium Ion batteries? I'd like to compare energy density of Petroleum Products based upon what limits can be obtained from stored energy in Lithium Ion.
I'm thinking something analogous to the Rankine Cycle for Steam Engines.

Comment: Of course there is, otherwise you would have portable black holes

Comment: Cross posting is not following recommendations, get the question moved between sites. (or delete then post on the other site). https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/425916/is-there-a-theoretical-performance-limit-for-lithium-ion-batteries

Comment: What kind of limit? storage limit? Voltage limit? The storage limit is 10x what batteries can store now, improvements in anode, cathode and electrolye materials will get us somwhere between 10x and where we are now. I don't think we want to have increases, any more energy stored and batteries will become bombs

Comment: See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/4328/whats-the-highest-theoretical-energy-density-for-a-chemical-battery?rq=1

Comment: I read an article saying the extra buffer space on lithium batteries is getting reduced more and more to save weight and space.  That's why the galaxy 7 phones would ignite.  So if you aren't asking about battery chemistry, and you are wondering about packaging, we are almost at the limit.